# How to get item type details in Jenkinfile?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to use the same Jenkinsfile for 2 different Jenkins jobs. One of them is using 'pipeline' item while the other is using 'multibranch pipeline'. Is it possible to differentiate between the item type within the Jenkinsfile at the time when a job is run? I search online but couldn't find much. Is there an environment variable which I could read?

Using the type information I have to trigger a downstream job, where I append the branch name to the job name in case the item type is a multi branch pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do that - which I found so far - is checking for the existence of the `BRANCH_NAME` environment variable which will only be set for a multibranch pipeline. We use that for our jobs.

For 100% safety you could instead check the data type of the current project. Taking the `currentBuild` object you could get the `rawBuild`. Having that you should be able to determine the data type of the project the build belongs to.

Comment: Thanks Joerg. Currently I added a boolean parameter in the 'pipeline' job, and since we cannot set parameters in a 'multi-pipeline' job I am checking there if the parameter exists or not. This is kind of similar to the first approach you suggested. I'll also try the second approach.